# Many to many in database but 1-to-1 in entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I started working on an ongoing project and it has a many-to-many relationship in the database and in some parts of the code too, but I realized that even the relationship being many-to-many in the model there is always only one line linking the two entities (confirmed with the author). This is what I mean: The two entities are task and task list and a task only belongs to a task list. Models below:

```
public class ProjectTask 
{
     public long Id { get; set; }     
    // other non related properties
}

public class ProjectTaskList
{
     public long Id { get; set; }    
     public DateTime? DateEnd { get; set; } 
     // other non related properties
}

// link between task list and task
public class ProjectTaskListTask
{
    public long ProjectTaskId { get; set; }
    public ProjectTask ProjectTask { get; set; }
    public long ProjectTaskListId { get; set; }
    public ProjectTaskList ProjectTaskList { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
}
```

And its configuration in the `OnModelCreating` method of the context class:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectTaskListTask>()
            .HasKey(a => new { a.ProjectTaskId, a.ProjectTaskListId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectTaskListTask>()
        .HasOne(u => u.ProjectTaskList)
        .WithMany(u => u.Tasks)
        .IsRequired()
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

My problem is: In some parts of my code I need to know the Task List of a task, I need to use it in `Where` queries to do some validations, like : `Tasks.Where(p => p.TaskList.DateEnd == null)`.

How can I add a Not Mapped property to the `ProjectTask` entity so I could do that? I'm using Entity Framework Core 2.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Just don't query it that way. *Technically* it's 1:n, so handle it in LINQ queries as 1:n. Pretend you know nothing of the business rule that there's always one junction record. Of course, when storing them you need a validation.

Comment: I presume this is the usual story "I can't change the database" etc., otherwise, if this is a hard constraint that's the first thing to do, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

Without changing the underlying data structure, could you query ProjectTaskListTask? Something along the lines...?

    `ProjectTaskListTask
    .Include(p => p.ProjectTaskList)
    .Include(p => p.ProjectTask)
    .Where(p => p.ProjectTaskList.DateEnd == null)
    .Select(p => p.ProjectTask);`

Comment: That was just an example of usage. I also need to configure the auto mapper and other things.